# Como enviar email diário?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, envio-de-email

Tenho uma aplicação em Ruby on Rails que preciso enviar um e-mail diário. Eu pensei em utilizar a própria [classe `Mailer`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) do `rails`. O que eu não sei é se é possível verificar a hora para realizar o envio automatizado utilizando o `rails`.

É possível usar um `timer` para fazer essa verificação e disparar o método de envio em um certo horário? Se não, existe alguma gem que realize esse trabalho?

Comment: Não conheço o Rails e os servidores dele, mas em servidores Linux para PHP é possível utilizar o Cron Jobs. Encontrei isso para Rails, vê se te ajuda: [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: @user157930 Daria só para explicar o uso do `Whenever`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguinte @Felipe eu tenho um servidor linux com 4 aplicações rails rodando nele. 
E também uma aplicação ruby que faz o disparo de alguns emails por dia, essa aplicação ruby é pequena e usa o [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) para o envio dos emails e tem um job no crontab sendo executado algumas vezes ao dia.
Vou colocar um exemplo dessa aplicação aqui bem simplificada.

Ela fica no diretório `/var/www/mensageria` dentro dele tenho os seguintes arquivos:

- mailer_config.rb (configurações do mailer smtp, usuário senha etc)
- notification_mailer.rb (Classe mailer)
- send.rb (Arquivo que dispara o email)

E tem uma pasta chamada `notification_mailer` e dentro dela um arquivo `alert.html.erb`.

No arquivo `mailer_config.rb` tem o seguinte código:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:                "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                   587,
    domain:                 "domain.com.br",
    authentication:         :plain,
    user_name:              "user",
    password:               "password",
    enable_starttls_auto:   true
}
```

No arquivo `notification_mailer.rb` tem o seguinte código:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_mailer'
require 'action_view'
require './mailer_config.rb'

class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'Nome do Remetente <email_remetente@email.com>'
    def alert(to,subject)
        mail(to: to, subject: subject) do |format|
            format.html { render './notification_mailer/alert.html.erb' }
        end
    end
end
```

No arquivo `send.rb` tem o seguinte código:

```
require './notification_mailer.rb'
NotificationMailer.alert('destinatario@email.com.br','Teste de Email').deliver
```

O arquivo `alert.html.erb` você coloca o conteúdo a ser enviado.

Ai agora só falta o crontab. Em um terminal no servidor rode:

`crontab -e` você pode editar como se estivesse editando um arquivo pelo [vim](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim)

```
0 6 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/mensageria && ruby send.rb'
```

Com isso ele vai executar o `send.rb` todos os dias as 06:00.

Comment: Só adicionaria a essa resposta a possibilidade do uso da [gem whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), que facilita o trabalho com o `crontab`. Fora isso, essa resposta me ajudou muito.